Opera signign keys re-appearing a day after deletion
I have a silly problem with Opera, which I installed, tried out, and purged completely from my system, but its signing keys are constantly re-appearing in mintsources. Why and how to prevent it?:


It took me a while to spot it, there is a cron.daily file /etc/cron.daily/opera-browser which does this:
$ cat /etc/cron.daily/opera-browser

#!/bin/sh

APT_CONFIG="`command -v apt-config 2> /dev/null`"

find_apt_trusted() {
  eval $("$APT_CONFIG" shell APT_TRUSTEDDIR 'Dir::Etc::trustedparts/d')
}

# Install the repository/package signing key (opera.archive.key.2021), if it isn't already.
install_key() {
  find_apt_trusted
  # ASCII-armored keyrings are only supported in apt 1.4 and later, but we must
  # continue supporting Trusty and Xenial which have older versions of apt, so
  # the keyring is installed as a binary blob.  base64 is used to decode the
  # ASCII keyring, which should always be available since it comes from the
  # coreutils.
  (base64 -d > "$APT_TRUSTEDDIR/opera.archive.key.2021.gpg") <<KEYDATA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==
KEYDATA
}

# Install another key (opera.archive.key.2023), if it isn't already, for future use.
install_future_key() {
  find_apt_trusted
  (base64 -d > "$APT_TRUSTEDDIR/opera.archive.key.2023.gpg") <<KEYDATA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==
KEYDATA
}

install_key
install_future_key


So, delete the file, and you should be done:
$ sudo rm /etc/cron.daily/opera-browser

Cheers
